How to update data from backend on form submit if i have a couple of components
I have a page where blocks in the format of text and date are displayed in a list format as shown in the screenshot below. These blocks are retrieved from the backend via an API, and this works well.
Here structure for block
Additionally, I have a button to "Add a new entry."
When I click on this button, a modal window appears with an input for text and a field for selecting a date. After filling in the fields and clicking "Submit," this data is sent to the backend to create a new entry.
The problem is that currently, to see the new entry, I have to reload the page, but I need to display it immediately without reloading the page.
const modal = (title, onSuccess) => {
    openModal(AddActivityModal, {
        onClose: closeModal,
        title: title,
        onSuccess: async () => {
            closeModal();
            setActivityDataUpdated(!activityDataUpdated);
        },
    })
}

I need somehow to update the data from the backend again when onSuccess() occurs in the modal window. This can be achieved using:
const {data, isFetching} = useActivities(props.status);
Mypage.js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import AppLayout from "../../layout/AppLayout";
import Activities from "../activity/Activities";
import ActivityDetails from "../activity/ActivityDetails";
import ActivityDetailsNoData from "../activity/ActivityDetailsNoData";
import AddActivityModal from "../modals/AddActivityModal";
import {useModal} from "../../contexts/ModalContext";

function ActivityPage(props) {
    const [activityId, setActivityId] = useState(null);
    const { closeModal, openModal } = useModal();
    const [activityDataUpdated, setActivityDataUpdated] = useState(false);

    const loadActivityDetails = (activityId) => {
        setActivityId(activityId);
    }

    const modal = (title, onSuccess) => {
        openModal(AddActivityModal, {
            onClose: closeModal,
            title: title,
            onSuccess: async () => {
                closeModal();
                setActivityDataUpdated(!activityDataUpdated);
            },
        })
    }

    return (
        <AppLayout>
            <h1 className="text-2xl pb-3 text-white">Activity</h1>

            <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-3">
                    <Activities
                        status="SUBMITTED"
                        title="Scheduled Scripts"
                        loadActivityHandler={loadActivityDetails}
                        openModal={() => modal("Create new")}
                        activityDataUpdated={activityDataUpdated}
                    />
                    <Activities
                        status="RUNNING"
                        title="Currently Running"
                        loadActivityHandler={loadActivityDetails}
                    />
                    <Activities
                        status="COMPLETED"
                        title="Run History"
                        loadActivityHandler={loadActivityDetails}
                    />
                </div>
                {activityId ? (
                    <div className="col-span-2 col-start-2">
                      <ActivityDetails activityId={activityId}/>
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <div className="col-span-2 col-start-2">
                      <ActivityDetailsNoData />
                    </div>
                  )
                }
            </div>
        </AppLayout>
    )
}

export default ActivityPage;

This is my component Activities
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import * as Icon from "react-bootstrap-icons";
import moment from "moment/moment";
import button from "bootstrap/js/src/button";
import {useActivities} from "../../api/activities";
import Loading from "../ui/Loading";

function Activities(props) {
    const {data, isFetching} = useActivities(props.status);
    
    const loadActivityDetails = (activityId) => {
        props.loadActivityHandler(activityId);
    }

    return (
      <div className="bg-widget rounded-md w-full px-3 pt-3 pb-6">
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
          <h1 className="text-2xl text-white">{props.title}</h1>
          {props.status === "SUBMITTED" && (
            <button onClick={props.openModal} className="btn btn-primary">Create new</button>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="bg-dark border-1 border-greyDark rounded mt-3">
          {isFetching ? (
            <Loading />
          ) : (
            data && data.results && data.results.length > 0 ? (
              data.results.map((item, index) => (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className="flex justify-between items-center px-3 py-2 border-b border-greyDark"
                >
                  <button className="text-left" onClick={() => loadActivityDetails(item.id)}>
                    <div className="font-bold">{item.id}{item.plan}</div>
                    <div>{moment(item.timestamp).format('DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm°')}</div>
                  </button>
                  <button className="flex gap-1 items-center bg-grey hover:bg-greyDark rounded py-2 px-2">
                    <Icon.List className="w-4 h-4 text-white" />
                    <Icon.CaretDownFill className="w-3 h-3 text-white" />
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))
            ) : (
              <p className="text-center py-3">No data</p>
            )
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Activities;

Also my API request
export const useActivityDetails = (activityId) => useQuery(
    {
        queryKey: [ACTIVITIES_DETAILS_QUERY_NAME, activityId],
        queryFn: () => api.get(`/activities/${activityId}`)
            .then((resp) => resp.data),
    }
)

I cant find a way how to fetch data again. Could anyone please help me?
Im trying to do some like this, but this is not allowed, what the other way to do this?
const { data, isFetching, activityDataUpdated } = useActivities(props.status); 
    useEffect(() => {
        if (activityDataUpdated) {
            useActivities(props.status);
        }
    }, [activityDataUpdated]);


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Added a more detailed description of the problem.

As I see it there are maybe 3 possible ways to go about this.
You could update the response so that it also returns the data, you could use the data you used to make the request to update or you can fetch the data again.
According to http standards, very approximately, post requests expect only the status and location of the resource, put and patch probably also don't expect much else other than status from the response. So you are free to implement if you want a response but it's maybe not the most in line with the http standard, but how much you care about that depends on your app, what you're doing and how you wanna go about it.
To update the components using data you may already have in state you would want to make sure it's set up in such a way it's easily accessible where you want to use it. So without seeing that part of the code can't really give much further advice there.
So to refetch, you just need to have the location of the resource, it seems you can fetch stuff with status attribute if props so unless maybe it was a new resource and you need the location, then it should work fine but you cannot call react hooks conditionally. Since hooks cannot be called conditionally, and must run the same number of times per render they should also not be called inside effects.
So there are a few ways to change the logic to fulfill the rules of hooks.
We can either modify the useActivies hook to return some refetch function that will cause the data to be refetched and update the returned data, which I think is the better solution, but to help more would need to have access to the hook's code.
But alternatively I guess you could add a state variable representing the status and update that which will cause the hook to rerun and refetch the data, something like.
const [status, setStatus] = useState(props.status); 

 ...

const {data, isFetching} = useActivities(status);

And then
useActivities(props.status); 
    useEffect(() => {
        setStatus({... props.status});
    }, [activityDataUpdated]);

And the useActivities hook should run again since the new status on state is spread so it's a new object, but really this seems like a bit of a workaround and I think the hook should probably return some refetch function.
And then just for completeness, you can eventually combine approaches such as updating from state and then from response further updating anything accordingly. So you first update on client as you make the request. Then if response is the same you don't need to do anything, if there are further fields to update you can update those, and also if the response is not success you can revert the client data, this is commonly know as optimistic updates.
Hope that helps

This was also my initial idea to do it through useEffect, but the problem lies in the fact that we cannot use a hook inside a callback. That is, I have such an error in the console:
React Hook "useActivities" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.
That's actually my problem because I can't find a way to do it.

yea my bad ahahah, I used to know this very well but I started using mainly solidjs its become a bit of a blur I guess ahaha, not trying to market anything but it is worth a try sometime. But yea, the idea I guess would be then to make a custom hook that does the updating, and then the hook can be called in the root of the funciton body. And should work, I'll update the answer with an example.

actually was a bit more complicated than I thought but I outlined that really I think the hook should have refetch logic, as that's probably the most sensible place to have it, otherwise I put a workaround but it just relies on abstracting the input of useActivies so you can update it from wherever.

but I do want to emphasize that I think the hook useActivities should be responsible for this kind of behaviour because you're relying on it to provide you the data. So I put a refetch function as just an example, but really, if within the hook you have all the request response logic then you can update the data state in there, but again to be able to inform better would have to post that code.
